# One of my biggest friends loves seeing a huge Ferris wheel. Who am I? And why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

- Hi. My name is five letters long, usually.
- One of my biggest friends loves seeing a huge Ferris wheel from across the river.
- My grandfather has a cool-looking swinging thingy in the house.
- I have kind of an OCD when it comes to "p" and "a".
- Some of my friends still use roman numerals in the 21st century. Old-fashioned, I know...
- Some of us have a bird in the house. Luckily, they don't sing incessantly.
- I rarely sleep (perhaps, only once in a few years?), but you can make me sleep any time.
- I love training my arms, but not legs.
- Now that most of you have mobile phones, you don't need me as often as you used to. Sad!
- The longer I cry like a baby, the more you'll hate me and want to dump me. But you can't live without me.
- Most of you don't want to see me on Sunday mornings.
- English-speaking people may call my name when eveything has gone according to plan.
- Your parents used to tell you not to point fingers at strangers, right? But I can't help it. At least, I don't do it to strangers, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> A Clock

Hi. My name is five letters long, usually.

> Clock has 5 letters

One of my biggest friends loves seeing a huge Ferris wheel from across the river.

> The palace of Westminster clock tower which houses Big Ben is across the Thames from the London Eye.

My grandfather has a cool-looking swinging thingy in the house.

> Grandfather Clocks have pendulums (or is it pendula?)

I have kind of an OCD when it comes to "p" and "a".

> am and pm

Some of my friends still use roman numerals in the 21st century. 
Old-fashioned, I know...

> Many clock faces have roman numerals

Some of us have a bird in the house. Luckily, they don't sing incessantly.

> Cuckoo clocks

I rarely sleep (perhaps, only once in a few years?), but you can make me sleep any time.

> If they run down, or if you stop them

I love training my arms, but not legs

> Not sure - perhaps the hands on a clock move, but the legs (if it has them) don't.

Now that most of you have mobile phones, you don't need me as often as you used to. Sad!

> Fewer people have clocks as mobile phones tell the time.

The longer I cry like a baby, the more you'll hate me and want to dump me. But you can't live without me.

> Alarm clocks are annoying but useful

Most of you don't want to see me on Sunday mornings.

> We like a lie in

English-speaking people may call my name when eveything has gone according to plan.

> Just like clockwork.

Your parents used to tell you not to point fingers at strangers, right? But I can't help it. At least, I don't do it to strangers, though...

> The big hand is pointing to xxx and the little hand is pointing to yyy

Comment: @Gordon K      Perfect logic through and through!